# What does "It's about damn time" mean in this article?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Excerpted from [the Atkantic](http://www.theatlantic.com/national/archive/2015/12/congress-women-military-combat/418785/):

> “**It’s about damn time**,” McSally said in a statement Thursday about the Pentagon’s decision. “We are a country that looks at people as individuals, not groups. We select the best man for the job, even if it’s a woman.”

What does she mean of "It's about damn time"? Why is the equality of gender related to time?

Comment: It's the **[it's about time](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/it-s-about-time)** idiom, with the word **damn** inserted into it to make it more expressive.

Comment: @CopperKettle That's the correct answer - why not post it as such, so that this question isn't marked as unanswered?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what did you mean by "Why is the equality of gender related to time?" ?

Comment: @VarunKN OP takes "about" to mean "related to, concerning".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*It's about damn time* does not mean "This concerns time" or "This is related to time"; it's an expanded version of the idiom "It's time", meaning the time for some action or event has arrived.

*About* is stressed in speech and is a heavily ironic use of *about* in the sense of *approximately* or *nearly* to express the speaker's feeling that the event in question is not merely *almost* due but long ***over***due.

*Damn* is an expletive, inserted for additional emotional emphasis.

Col./Rep. McSally is saying that Pentagon's decision to allow women to serve in combat units should have happened a long time ago.

Comment: Too wordy, but accurate. Upvoted.

Comment: Also made famous by King James http://66.media.tumblr.com/8b1e54ac6463eadbbd55ba000feeb126/tumblr_inline_nod90tqw7n1ro2rbc_500.gif